# Как переписать функцию чтоб она не использовала callback-функции возвращала промис

Tags: javascript

Суть задания: нужно переписать функцию makeTransaction() так, чтобы она не использовала callback-функции onSuccess и onError, а принимала всего один параметр transaction и возвращала промис.Использую промис с resolve и reject. Подскажите пожалуйста правильное решения этого задания. Изучаю промисы и хотелось бы хорошо их понимать. Заранее спасибо тем кто поможет! Я сделала изменения которые мне здесь подсказали но у меня почему то не выводит переменную time. Не могу понять в чем причина? Вот мое решение:

```js
const randomIntegerFromInterval = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

const makeTransaction = transaction => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const delay = randomIntegerFromInterval(200, 500);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const canProcess = Math.random() > 0.3;
      if (canProcess) {
        resolve([transaction.id, delay]);
      } else {
        reject([transaction.id]);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
};

const logSuccess = (id, time) => {
  console.log(`Transaction ${id} processed in ${time}ms`);
};

const logError = id => {
  console.warn(`Error processing transaction ${id}. Please try again later.`);
};


makeTransaction({ id: 70, amount: 150 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);

makeTransaction({ id: 71, amount: 230 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);

makeTransaction({ id: 72, amount: 75 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);

makeTransaction({ id: 73, amount: 100 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);
```

Comment: Скобки вокруг аргументов забыл: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...});`

Comment: Спасибо! Исправила но все равно не работает time

Comment: Функции resolve/reject принимают ровно один аргумент – результат/ошибку. Т.е. вместо `resolve(transaction.id, delay)` нужно вернуть `resolve([transaction.id, delay]);` или `resolve({id: transaction.id, time: delay});` или что-то подобное, а в обработчике деструктурировать

Comment: Спасибо сделала правки которые вы предложили. Но все равно я сомневаюсь в правильности написания своего кода сейчас попробую отредактировать вопрос

Comment: Да, конечно - ведь резолвится **одно** значение, поэтому обработчик в `then` не получает второй аргумент `time`. Просто резолви объект вида `{id: transaction.id, time: delay}`. В аргументах `logSuccess` можно будет использовать его деструктуризацию: `({id, time}) => {...}`.

Comment: Сорри за дублирование, надо было мне обновить страничку перед тем как постить.

Comment: Ничего страшного) Спасибо за помощь) я понимаю о чем вы говорите но сделать пока никак какой-то ступор)

Comment: `const logSuccess = ( [ id, time ] ) => {` https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment

Comment: https://jsbin.com/cekojoziga/edit?js,console

Comment: Я опубликую ответ сделанный с Вашей помощью ) Если что пишите

Answer (score 0):

> Функция resolve/reject ожидает только один аргумент (или ни одного).
>   Все дополнительные аргументы будут проигнорированы.

```js
const randomIntegerFromInterval = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

const makeTransaction = transaction => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const delay = randomIntegerFromInterval(200, 500);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const canProcess = Math.random() > 0.3;
      if (canProcess) {
        resolve({ id: transaction.id, time: delay });
      } else {
        reject(transaction.id);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
};

const logSuccess = ({ id, time }) => {
  console.log(`Transaction ${id} processed in ${time}ms`);
};

const logError = id => {
  console.warn(`Error processing transaction ${id}. Please try again later.`);
};

   
makeTransaction({ id: 70, amount: 150 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);

makeTransaction({ id: 71, amount: 230 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);

makeTransaction({ id: 72, amount: 75 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);

makeTransaction({ id: 73, amount: 100 })
  .then(logSuccess)
  .catch(logError);
```